# Landingpage errorcode

Tags: marketing-cloud

I created a landingpage where it is saving to a data extension. We entered a custom _errorPage, but when we fill in a existing email address it is always giving is &ErrorCode=2. Why is that??? Following the documentation here: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/#section_23
it is saying that entering the same data must give us error code 8 right??

The errorcode 2 is: ""The list provided does not exist".", but we don't do anything with a list on the landingspage.

This is the ampscript for the processing:

```
VAR @de, @de_col, @de_statusCode, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode

SET @de = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@de, "CustomerKey", "")


IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("email")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "email")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("email"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("bedrijfsnaam")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "bedrijfsnaam")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("bedrijfsnaam"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("contactpersoon_voorletters")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "contactpersoon_voorletters")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("contactpersoon_voorletters"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("contactpersoon_voornaam")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "contactpersoon_voornaam")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("contactpersoon_voornaam"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("contactpersoon_tussenvoegsel")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "contactpersoon_tussenvoegsel")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("contactpersoon_tussenvoegsel"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("contactpersoon_achternaam")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "contactpersoon_achternaam")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("contactpersoon_achternaam"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("bron")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "bron")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("bron"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("contactpersoon_geslacht")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "contactpersoon_geslacht")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("contactpersoon_geslacht"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF


SET @de_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@de, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode)

IF @de_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@de_statusMsg, 0, @de_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF
```

What i want to do is creating a error page what is saying more then, "There went something wrong.".

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the Data Extension name you want to insert the record into:
SetObjectProperty(@de, "CustomerKey", "***DATAEXTENSIONNAME***")

Comment: Also note that if you didn't give the Data Extension a Customer Key you will need to use the GUID that gets assigned automatically. I'd suggest giving the Customer Key the same value as the Data Extension Name.